How to configure key press repeat delay?
I have less-than-perfect connection to a Centos & machine via VNC. One problem is a slow echo; a worse one is a keypress repeat. When I type, say, cat, at normal speed, a couple seconds later I see cattttttt. Is it possible to modify the keyboard repeat character delay or just disable it?

From what I understand, CentOS defaults to GNOME as its DE. You ought to be able to change it pursuant to this answer on AskUbuntu

These settings are under Settings → Universal Access → Typing → Repeat Keys. You have to click the Repeat Keys row item, which brings up a pop-up dialog with two settings: Delay and Speed.

If that doesn't work / you're running a different DE and you're using X11 as a display server, you can use xset. In the case of your connection, you can turn key repeat off completely with:
$ xset off

Implementation differs if you're using another Wayland compositor.
